# Проблема с разрешением экрана и xrandr не работает

Tags: debian

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        0.00*

При попытке добавить новый режим - xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00" 106.50 1440 1528 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Делал уже всё что угодно - ничего не помогло :(

Comment: Установка драйвера видеокарты входила в это «делал уже всё что угодно»?

Comment: Драйвер и так обнаружен, у меня видеокарта ati radeon hd 4300/4500 series rv710

Comment: Что означает «Драйвер и так обнаружен»? Пакет fglrx или xserver-xorg-video-radeon установлен?

Comment: с самого начала я устанавливал как раз таки xserver-xorg-video-radeon, а fglrx не ставится, да и без него всё везде работало(видимо), именно почему то дебиан шалит :(